# Python: HTTP request automaticly cut off strings of content

Tags: python, http, post, request

I'm trying to send an HTTP post request with Python 2.4. I analyzed the post request with wireshark and the request contains in the data only *"options=user:jo"* instead of *"options=user:john"*. Any suggestions why python cut off the last two characters. This happens also with shorter and longer strings. I have to use these libs and Python 2.4.

Thanks for reply

My Script:

```
import base64
import httplib

data_string = urllib.urlencode({'options':'user:john'})

authheader =  'Basic ' + base64.encodestring("restuser:restbpm")

headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Authorization": authheader}

h = httplib.HTTPConnection('localhost:8080')

h.request('POST', '/bonita-server-rest/API/runtimeAPI/instantiateProcess/Leitungsauskunft--1.9', data_string, headers)

r = h.getresponse()

print r.read()
```

Еxcerpt from wireshark

```
TCP

TCP segment data (17 bytes)  ..options=user:jo

TCP segment data (2 bytes)   hn

HTTP

Line-based text data: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

\r\n

options=user:jo
```

Еxcerpt from Server log

```
Mai 07, 2013 4:29:41 PM org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve invoke
INFO:             header=authorization=Basic cmVzdHVzZXI6cmVzdGJwbQ==
Mai 07, 2013 4:29:41 PM org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve invoke
INFO:             locale=de_DE
Mai 07, 2013 4:29:41 PM org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve invoke
INFO:             method=POST
Mai 07, 2013 4:29:41 PM org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve invoke
INFO:          parameter=
options=user:jo 
Mai 07, 2013 4:29:41 PM org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve invoke
INFO:           pathInfo=/API/runtimeAPI/instantiateProcess/Leitungsauskunft--1.9
Mai 07, 2013 4:29:41 PM org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve invoke
INFO:           protocol=HTTP/1.1
Mai 07, 2013 4:29:41 PM org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve invoke
INFO:        queryString=null
```

Error from Python script

```
<java.lang.IllegalArgumentException>
  <detailMessage>The options are null or not well set.</detailMessage>
<stackTrace>
    <trace>org.ow2.bonita.facade.impl.AbstractRemoteRuntimeAPIImpl.getAPI(AbstractRemoteRuntimeAPIImpl.java:62)</trace>
    <trace>org.ow2.bonita.facade.impl.AbstractRemoteRuntimeAPIImpl.instantiateProcess(AbstractRemoteRuntimeAPIImpl.java:178)</trace>
    <trace>sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor50.invoke(Unknown Source)</trace>
    <trace>sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)</trace>
    <trace>java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)</trace>
    <trace>org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:124)</trace>
    <trace>org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:247)</trace>
    <trace>org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:212)</trace>
    <trace>org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:202)</trace>
    <trace>org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:441)</trace>
    <trace>org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:418)</trace>
    <trace>org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:111)</trace>
    <trace>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:217)</trace>
    <trace>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:159)</trace>
    <trace>javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)</trace>
    <trace>org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)</trace>
    <trace>org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)</trace>
    <trace>org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)</trace>
    <trace>org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)</trace>
    <trace>org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)</trace>
    <trace>org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)</trace>
    <trace>org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)</trace>
    <trace>org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:615)</trace>
    <trace>org.bonitasoft.console.security.SessionFixationValve.invoke(SessionFixationValve.java:77)</trace>
    <trace>org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)</trace>
    <trace>org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve.invoke(RequestDumperValve.java:156)</trace>
    <trace>org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)</trace>
    <trace>org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)</trace>
    <trace>org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)</trace>
    <trace>org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)</trace>
    <trace>java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)</trace>
  </stackTrace>
  <suppressedExceptions class="java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList" resolves-to="java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList">
    <c class="list"/>
    <list reference="../c"/>
  </suppressedExceptions>
```

Server log after adding Content Length to Header

```
Mai 08, 2013 2:03:19 PM org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve invoke
INFO:          parameter=
options=user:john
```

Python with urllib2 code

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import base64
import sys

url = "http://localhost:8080/bonita-server-rest/API/runtimeAPI/instantiateProcess/Leitungsauskunft--1.9"
data_string = urllib.urlencode({'options':'user:john'})

request_object = urllib2.Request(url, data_string)


authheader =  'Basic ' + base64.encodestring("restuser:restbpm")

request_object.add_header('Authorization', authheader)
request_object.add_header('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
request_object.add_header('Content-length','21')


try: response = urllib2.urlopen(request_object).read()
except IOError, e: 
    print e.code
    print e.headers
```

Comment: Python doesn't cut off the data, but individual TCP packets may show you only part of it. Why not use `urllib2` to do the work here? Or better still, upgrade Python to 2.6 *at least* and use [`requests`](http://python-requests.org/) instead. Python 2.4 is **ancient**.

Comment: Hey thanks for reply, if i use urllib2 the same happens. An upgrade to Python 2.6 isn't possible :(. Requests is great but not available for Python 2.4. Do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: *Python* is not truncating your data. Try using `httpbin.org:80` as the host, and `/post` as the path, then use `import json; print json.load(r)` to see what that server thinks you posted.

Comment: Json isn't available for python 2.4. Maybe the server logs help you.

Comment: Just print `r.read()` then; JSON results are very readable without decoding.

Comment: I posted the exception in the question. Thanks a lot for your engagement

Comment: I see that you are indeed appear to be missing data. Perhaps you need to add a `Content-Length` header to better communicate how much data you are sending?

Comment: Also, it is not clear to me why you can't use `urllib2` here.

Comment: I only want to sent this string "options=user:john". I have also tried this with urllib2 it throws the same error.I will post my urllib2 code and the new serverlog. IF i add Conten-Length to header the string is now complete "options=user:john" but there is still a line break.

Comment: Your `urllib2` code looks correct to me (albeit with redundant `Content-*` headers, those are added for you), and certainly works correctly when I test those locally. This appears to be a problem *outside* of Python.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its really strange i tried to do this with Request lib and Python 2.7 i used the same headers, same authentication, and same data field and it works. If i compare the server logs between this method and Pythpn 2.4 with Urllib there is only one big different parameter=... .

Comment: Testing some more with urllib2 vs requests I certainly see small differences, but nothing big enough to cause this. You'd need to capture the headers and post body exactly (using a proxy perhaps) to see what is different and what Java doesn't like about that.

Comment: Here you see the different in the server log http://s14.directupload.net/images/130508/bxjxxd2z.jpg 27 means Python with Requests(works) and 24 means Python with urllib2(doesnt work). If Python with urllib2 create a post request with correct parameter like Python with Requets i think my script will work

Comment: That almost looks as if the server thinks there is an extra newline after the headers somehow. Header separators are `\r\n`, two characters, exactly the number of characters you are missing from the end of your value.

Comment: At this stage I'd set up some proxy or server to capture the full request in transit, and start comparing it with working requests to see what the hell is different and what I could tweak. Once you have the specific character sequences that cause the problem, we can start working out what generates those and if that is a Python problem or a problem on the Java end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an Answer for the problem. Behind this line

```
authheader =  'Basic ' + base64.encodestring("restuser:restbpm")
```

you have to add this `[:-1]`.

In this example you see why.

```
import base64
authheader =  'Basic ' + base64.encodestring("restuser:restbpm")
authheader
'Basic cmVzdHVzZXI6cmVzdGJwbQ==\n'
authheader =  'Basic ' + base64.encodestring("restuser:restbpm")[:-1]
authheader
'Basic cmVzdHVzZXI6cmVzdGJwbQ=='
```

By the encoding he put this at the end `\n` which creates the line break inside the http request and the `[:-1]` cut off this character.

Thanks a lot for help ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Bräd Wurst's answer.

From base64 docs:

> base64.encodestring(s) Encode the string s, which can contain
>   arbitrary binary data, and return a string containing one or more
>   lines of base64-encoded data. encodestring() returns a string
>   containing one or more lines of base64-encoded data always including
>   an extra trailing newline ('\n').

But, using `base64.standard_b64encode(s)` should help in this case:

```
import base64
authheader = 'Basic ' + base64.standard_b64encode("restuser:restbpm")
authheader
'Basic cmVzdHVzZXI6cmVzdGJwbQ=='
```